# Use mathrm by default for uppercase Latin characters

Tags: xetex, mathspec

I'm trying to mix Optima and AMS Euler using eulervm and mathspec in XeLaTeX. The relevant bit of code in my source file is as follows:

```
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathfont(Digits)[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Optima nova LT Pro}
\setmathrm{Optima nova LT Pro}
```

Using this set up, Euler is used in math mode unless I specify `\mathrm`. For Greek and lowercase Latin characters this works out quite well, but for uppercase Latin I would very much prefer to use Optima's glyphs.

My current workaround is to stick `\mathrm` around every uppercase Latin variables in math mode, however this gets rather annoying after a while. Is there any way to coax XeLaTeX into using `\mathrm` by default only for uppercase Latin glyphs?

Comment: I don't think that `mathspec` allows for specifying different fonts for Latin letters

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately `mathspec` doesn't allow for specifying separately uppercase and lowercase letters.